# Julia dictionary keys curiosity

Tags: julia

Consider the following code:

```
dog = (a=5, b=6, c=7)
frog = Dict(pairs(dog))
frog.keys
```

returns:

```
16-element Vector{Symbol}:
:a
:b
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 :c
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

Now, I am well aware that to get the keys of a dictionary the standard way is `keys(frog)`, which does do the right thing, but what is the `keys` attribute of a dictionary, and why is it so weird?

Comment: You can use tab complete in the REPL after typing `frog.` to see all the variable names in the struct. [Here is the relevant code from Base.Dict](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d6baad629e9103a47c6286421f12a334a0b59fc5/base/dict.jl#L57-L66)

Answer (score 9):

Because `Dict` is a hash table. The locations are determined by hash values of keys modulo table size which is 16 in this case:

```
julia> (((hash(:a) % Int) & (16-1)) + 1)
1

julia> (((hash(:b) % Int) & (16-1)) + 1)
2

julia> (((hash(:c) % Int) & (16-1)) + 1)
10
```

There is a special case though:

```
julia> dog = (a=5, b=6, f=7)
(a = 5, b = 6, f = 7)

julia> frog = Dict(pairs(dog))
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 3 entries:
  :a => 5
  :b => 6
  :f => 7

julia> frog.keys
16-element Vector{Symbol}:
    :a
    :b
    :f
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> (((hash(:f) % Int) & (16-1)) + 1)
1
```

As you can see now `:a` and `:f` have index collision, so for `:f` the new index needs to be computed (you can see the details how this is done in the code that Ashlin Harris linked in the comment to your question).

Comment: Yes, thank you, this was the obvious answer. What was NOT obvious (and still is not) is why this (rather ugly) implementations detail is exposed to the user. In other words, just because a Dict is implemented as a hash table, does not mean that these details should be visible.

Comment: This is a design decision of Julia. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Prefer-exported-methods-over-direct-field-access. Typically fields of a struct are considered private.

Comment: I am confused. The link you provided explicitly says that it is a bad idea to do what they have done here.

Comment: The general spirit of Julia is to let users poke around the insides of structs, modules, Base, etc. Although this is dangerous, it also allows quick hacks which can develop into more robust API changes. Julia doesn't assume programmers are malicious, and it assumes they recognize the line between APIs and internals (but this is indeed a vague philosophy).

Comment: @IgorRivin What have they done here that is a bad idea? Afaict, it is you who are accessing internal fields, and that is discouraged, or at least you should not write code that depends on internal unexported symbols in another module/package. You can also easily access the source code, if you like, but it is not considered a good idea to modify it.

Comment: @DNF A door or window cannot really prevent someone from entering, but it is there to say that the person in the house would rather you knock. Ceremonially protecting various fields of structs serves the same purpose. Notice that here there is not even the name masking by underscores, etc (not  even to mention access via functions, as suggested in the link). Someone (like me) can easily accidentally stumble onto this internal implementation feature, Not clean.

Comment: I understand your concern. Though, let me share with you my experience. I have used Julia every day for the last 10 years. What you mention has never be a problem. Though, I can see it might be an issue if someone is used to accessing fields of a struct using `.` (e.g. coming from Python). In Julia you in practice almost never do this.

Comment: @IgorRivin In Python you have the leading underscore to signal privacy, in Julia the dot-access signals privacy. Access to fields via api calls are of course fine (and intended), just like calls access _fields in python.

Comment: BTW, doors are, of course, present to *allow* people to enter, not to prevent them ;)

Comment: @DNF Yes, I actually meant locks